# Strange issue, space of my UISearchController

Tags: ios, constraints, uisearchcontroller

The issue is like this:

There has space between `searchbar` and `navbar`:

And in the `Debug in Hierarchy`:

The table View

[image]

The wrapper View, we can see the space (20 pix)

[image: The wrapper View]

And in the `storyboard`, I set the constraint to the `tableView`, attention: the `navigationBar` is draged by myself, the native is hide by me.

---

**My Code**

```
import UIKit
import SVProgressHUD

class StoreListViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, UISearchResultsUpdating {

@IBOutlet weak var navbar: UINavigationBar!

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var ori_dataSource: [StoreListModel] = [StoreListModel]()
var dataSource = [String]()
var filterdDataSource = [String]()
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()
var choosedStore:StoreListModel? = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    initData()
    initUI()
}

// MARK: - init
func initData()  {
    
    self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    self.resultSearchController.searchBar.placeholder = "search"
    self.resultSearchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
    self.resultSearchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar
    
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "TerantListCell", bundle: nil)
    // Required if our subclasses are to use: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:
    //tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TerantListCell")
    self.tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TerantListCell")
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView.init()
    
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    
    networkForStoreList()
}
func initUI() {
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



 // MARK: - Navigation
 
 // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
 // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    
    if segue.identifier == "StoreListGotoStoreDetailVC" {
        
        let detail_vc:StoreDetailVC = segue.destination as! StoreDetailVC
        detail_vc.store_info = self.choosedStore
        
    }
    
 }


// MARK: - delegate
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked() {
    
    for item:NSLayoutConstraint in self.tableView.constraints {
        
        if item.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.top {
            item.constant = 0
        }
    }
  
}

// MARK: - searchbar delegate
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    
    searchBar.setValue("cancel", forKey:"_cancelButtonText")
    
    for item:NSLayoutConstraint in self.navbar.constraints {

        if item.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.height {
            item.constant = 0
        }
    }
    
    
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    
    for item:NSLayoutConstraint in self.navbar.constraints {
        
        if item.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.height {
            
            item.constant = 64
        }
    }
    
}

// MARK: - private methods


// MARK: - actions

// MARK: - unwind
@IBAction func unwindToStoreListVCFromStoreDetailVC(segue: UIStoryboardSegue)  {
    
    
}


// MARK: - network

func networkForStoreList() {
    
    let userStatic: UserStaticSwift = UserStaticSwift.sharedInstance()
    
    let params:[String:String] = [
        "createTime":"-1",
        "userId" : userStatic.userId  
    ]
    
    // url_listUsers
    Mysevers.afpost(withHud: true, andAddressname: Global.url_listStore, parmas: params, requestSuccess: { (result) in
        
        let stateCode = UtilSwift.getNetStateCode(result: result as Any, key: Global.net_key_stateCode)
        
        if stateCode == 0 {
            
            let userArr:[[String : Any]] = UtilSwift.getNetAnyObject(result: result as Any, key: "list") as! [[String : Any]]  // Global.net_key_bussiness  
            //self.ori_dataSource = terantArr
            for item:[String: Any] in userArr {
                
                let store_list_model: StoreListModel = StoreListModel.initStoreListModelWithDic(dic: item)
                self.ori_dataSource.append(store_list_model)
            }
            
            for item:StoreListModel in self.ori_dataSource {
                
                self.dataSource.append(item.name)
            }
            
            self.tableView.reloadData()   
            
        }else if stateCode == -1 {
            
            SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: "err")
        }
        
    }, failBlcok: {
        
            SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: "fail")
        })
    
    }

    // MARK: - tableView
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
        if self.resultSearchController.isActive {
        
            return filterdDataSource.count
        }else {
        
            return dataSource.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
        let cell: TerantListCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TerantListCell", for: indexPath) as! TerantListCell
    
        if self.resultSearchController.isActive {
        
            cell.title_label.text = self.filterdDataSource[indexPath.row]
        }else {
        
            cell.title_label?.text = self.dataSource[indexPath.row]
        }
    
        return cell
    
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
        self.choosedStore = self.ori_dataSource[indexPath.row]
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "StoreListGotoStoreDetailVC", sender: self)
    
    }

    // MARK: -

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    
        self.filterdDataSource.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
    
        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    
        let array = (self.dataSource as NSArray).filtered(using: searchPredicate)
    
        self.filterdDataSource = array as! [String]
    
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


}
```

---

**ATTEMPT - 1**

When I `uncheck` the `Adjust Scroll View Insets`, first come into the `vc`,  the issue is nonexistent, but if I click the `searchBar`, the issue will come again, I suspect my code if is somewhere mistake:

---

**ATTEMPT - 2**

If I try this code below:

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    
    for item:NSLayoutConstraint in self.navbar.constraints {
        
        if item.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.height {
            
            item.constant = 44 // before is 64.
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: brother you use default navigation controller ?

Comment: @Himanshu Moradiya, yeah, but the `navigationBar` is draged by myself. because I think do this I can convenient edit the `navigationBar`, the default `navigationBar` is hidden by me.

Comment: did you set frame of your tableview and searchbar in coding when it editing changes . ?

Comment: func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    for item:NSLayoutConstraint in self.navbar.constraints {

        if item.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.height {

            item.constant = 44 // changes this 
        }
    }

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempt:

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    for item:NSLayoutConstraint in self.navbar.constraints {

        if item.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.height {

            item.constant = 64
        }
    }

    // set this help me! :)
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know how you constraints your views. I guess the problem is due to `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets`. You should `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` of your `ViewController`. Or you should constraints your `UITableView` to `View.Top` instead of `TopLayoutGuide.Bottom`.

Comment: I have tested uncheck the `AdjustsScrollViewInsets` in storyboard, but there still have the issue, check my `EDIT - 1`

Comment: it would be great to know how you constraint your navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    for item:NSLayoutConstraint in self.navbar.constraints {

        if item.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.height {

            item.constant = 44 // changes this one line and check it if any problem then put comment below.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @aircraft your tableview top constrain = 0; ?

Comment: @aircraft did you update your output result gif file with constant value = 44

Comment: .You can see my `Debug in Hierarchy:` picture, at there, `the tableView`'s bottom view is okay, top to `navigationBar`'s bottom, but the `searchbar `'s position, is offset, not begin with the `wrapperView`'s top.

Comment: ya i see it i dont understand why this problem you face.

Comment: Thank you , I solved the crazy issue, see my answer, tanks again your help.