# UISearchController weird behavior on dismissing it

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I am adding `UISearchController` searchBar to the controllers' view like this: `self.view.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)`. The functionality is working perfectly fine except that upon selection of the tableview row the searchbar quickly moves down and reappears from the top. I tried the following things, none of which worked out:

1. Setting `tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar` instead of directly adding to the view
2. Adding `searchController.searchBar` to a separate view that I dragged to the controller setting up constraints on it. Tried clipping to bounds both the newly created view and the searchBar.
3. Embedding the controller in `UINavigationViewController` and setting `self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar`. I defined the frame of the searchBar, still nothing.
4. Tried playing with `Extend Edges` feature in the storyboard (Under top bars, etc.), but no selection worked out
5. Adding lines (to `viewDIdLoad`):

   `self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true`

   `self.definesPresentationContext = true`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you mean click the cancel button, the tableView move down from the origin place?

Comment: Yep, and this too. Basically when we do `searchController.active = false` it moves down, then comes out from the top

Comment: I know this issue, I answer it in there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40991848/strange-issue-space-of-my-uisearchcontroller, if it helps you.

Comment: Nope, not fixing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying all of the suggestion and searching over the internet, it caught my eye that the working examples of the `UISearchController` implementation are done in `UITableViewController`, but I had `UIViewController` with `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols on it. Unfortunately, due to app architecture I was not able to directly have `UITableViewController`, so I needed to restructure the app, so that it had `UINavigationController` where I embeded the `searchBar` in `navigationItem.titleView` (and not set it as `tableView.tableHeaderView` like they always do in various tutorials since I needed the `searchBar` to be fixed, not hidden when we do scrolling) and it worked. Here is how the ultimate working app architecture looks like:

[image]

The `TrainingContainerViewController` has two `Container View`s, in one we embed `TrainingFilterTableViewController` that shows up the ultimate results of the autocomplete functionality (after clicking on an autocomplete row). Another `Container View` embeds `UINavigationController` (to the left) which, in turn, has `TrainingSearchTableViewController` as its child.

The code that sets up the `UISearchController` and its `searchBar` is located in the `TrainingSearchTableViewController`s' `viewDidLoad` and is the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchController.delegate = self
    navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
    tableView.hidden = true

    ...
}
```

Nothing else was needed to fix the bug in `XCode 8.2.1` and `Swift 2.3`, just change architecture, so that usage of `UITableViewController` is possible in the app and use it instead of `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboards, you can change it by selecting the view controller and in the attributes inspector deselect Adjust scroll view insets.

Comment: Nope, it does not help